# detect touchstart only if element has a specific class

Tags: jquery, touchstart

I am listening for an event with JQuery as follows:

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', '.open-qv', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
```

However I only want to listen for/detect `touchstart` if the element touched has a specific class eg. `.hotspot`   If it doesn't have this class I only want to listen for click, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `event.type` to check that either event is not touchstart or element `.hasClass()` hotspot:

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', '.open-qv', function(e){
  if(event.type!="touchstart" || $(this).hasClass('hotspot') ){
     //do stuff
  }
```